# Why does to "to live a dog's life" have opposite meanings in the UK and US

Tags: idioms

In the US, to "lead a dog's life" means to be to be comfortable, even pampered. In the UK it means to have a terrible, harassed life. This is especially odd because the UK is notoriously dog loving.

Comment: The only American dictionary I found it in, [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/a%20dog%27s%20life) gives the meaning "a difficult, boring, and unhappy life". Can you provide citations for both meanings (and explain any research or observation you've done), because I'm not sure it's a US v UK thing (it might be a generational thing or something else).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there is no evidence (other than anecdotal) to suggest that the meanings differ in AE and BE.

Comment: According to Lady Florence Paget, the 3rd Duke of Sutherland's wife “led him a dog’s life, but he, being weak, could not extricate himself from her toils”.

Comment: I am a reasonably well-read UK native speaker, interested in usages, and have never heard this expression used other than to mean 'an exceptionally miserable life'.

Comment: As the answer makes clear, the phrase is sometimes used for pampered life, even though that may be comparatively rare, so there is genuine need for an explanation of how the phrase came to have two apparently contradictory meanings (even if it turns out that that the OP is wrong about that being a difference between American and British English). The question should therefore be reopened.

Comment: @Greybeard If you think the OP is wrong in their assumptions, that's not a reason to close. It's the best time to provide an answer that you think explains things.

Answer (score 3):

Michael Quinion responded to a reader's question about this in [World Wide Words](http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-its1.htm); but said that "I’ve not come across many examples myself of its use as a description of a pampered existence".

This seems to suggest that the disparity (if it's real) is generational rather than geographic.

Neither that correspondent, nor the [Wiktionary entry](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dog%27s_life) (which lists both meanings) gives an example of the use; and looking at the instances phrase in the iWeb corpus I find it is hard to tell from the snippets which sense might be meant but some of them probably have this apparently newer sense. One example from there which probably has this sense is from "morethan.com" (an insurance provider): "... to the hotel dining room and can sleep in your room. It's a dog 's life!"

As to why: well, "why" questions about language are notoriously hard to answer. The Wiktionary entry says "Originally the term referred to the hard life of the working dog: sleeping in a damp barn, chasing rats and other intruders, living on scraps, etc. Today, however, it has in some circles acquired the completely opposite connotation indicated in sense 2", but that is not cited to a source, so is probably one editor's conclusion.

Comment: I suspect that the bridge between the two meanings is that some people, while fully aware of the original meaning, started using it for pampered life **as a joke**; the example quoted here may **arguably** be of that kind, but it is difficult to be sure. Some other people, who were not aware of the original meaning, heard such usage, and not realising that it was intended humorously, picked it up.

Comment: The lovely lady who was taking her dog for a walk near Bell Rock (near Sedona, Arizona) that my wife and I met while on a coach tour some years ago made me wonder who are really the dog-lovers. We'd never seen a dog in a pram before.